# C# - how to find a laser spot in two photos?

Tags: c#

Suppose you have two identical photos of a stationary object, but in one of them a red laser pointer is shining at your object. And now you need to find the exact location of that laser spot.

I tried Aforge's difference filter, but the results weren't very good. Maybe you could suggest a better way?

Considering, that the laser spot is brighter, photos could be compared using some kind of "if lighter" algorithm, rather then just "difference"...

Thanks )

Comment: Two identical photos that are different? Like the question, this rapidly deviates from anything to do with code. An interesting problem but almost certainly off topic.

Comment: yes, one of them has a laser shining onto the object.

Comment: I'd suggest adding some sample code to prove you have attempted to solve this yourself otherwise I suspect this question will get down voted and closed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Algorithm to compare two images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23931/algorithm-to-compare-two-images)

Comment: @Jodrell, on reading, not strictly a duplicate but useful

Comment: The problem is, that this sounds simple because the human brain is really good at doing it without concious thought. Consider the steps and evaluations involved.

Comment: @RogerTravis it also probably has tons of other changes: slight movement in camera and/or zoom, movement of shadows, background things such as birds, cars, pedestrians - all move; light levels vary (perhaps due to something out of shot); or even just encoding artefacts; the images will be very different at the pixel level. The trick is how to turn that into *relative* differences, ignoring all those things. Which is: not trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simplify your problem, You want to compare two images.

Here is the first link which compares the images and looks for rate of similarity
https://github.com/cameronmcefee/Image-Diff-View-Modes/commit/8e95f70c9c47168305970e91021072673d7cdad8

You could also look at [Viisage](http://www.sourcesecurity.com/technical-details/access-control/access-control-systems-and-kits.2/access-control-systems-and-kits/viisage-faceexplorer.html) FaceExplorer, and [Lead Tools](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/po/leadtools.imageprocessing.core~leadtools.imageprocessing.core.correlationcommand.html) which serve these functions.